# jquery ui draggable negative z-index

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Why draggable doesn't works with negative z-index ? 
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/yEHCA/1/ 
How to drag second image from example above ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporary solution: change z-index on start/stop 
http://jsfiddle.net/yEHCA/60/

Answer (score 2):

In your example the square with z-index=-1 is placed behind the grid, so when you try to drag it you are actually clicking on the grid.

If you set a z-index lower than -1 for the grid, it works:
http://jsfiddle.net/yEHCA/15/

Why do you need to use negative z-index?